# Staircase problem with custom step intervals

Tags: algorithm

I understand the classic staircase problem when you can step either 1, 2, or 3 times and display the unique ways you can reach the nth step. But I being asked to allow the user to enter any interval steps they wish as well as the size of the staircase. e.g. staircase size 10 with intervals of {1,3,5}. I am struggling to understand the algorithm needed to accomplish this at a conceptual level and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `C++` -- This is an algorithm question, and is not specific to any language.

Comment: You may be able to apply [this](https://www.includehelp.com/cpp-programs/stair-case-program-to-solve-the-staircase-problem.aspx) answer. It allows for steps of 1 2 or 3, but instead you would just run a loop in the body of the function to do each quantity of steps in your array i.e. `{1,3,5}`.

Comment: For C++, I'd guess the partition algorithm from the STL could be applied to this problem.  The question can be generalized as "How many ways can n elements be partitioned into groups of x, y, or z?" (and assuming you can only step up never down). Note some combinations will not have even a single solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of size `N` where arr[i] represents the number of ways to reach the `i'th` step from the first step.

The Relation between any step `i` and the step_array is:-

```
for step in step_array:
    arr[i]=arr[i]+arr[i-step]
```

You'll have to repeat this for each value of i.

### Why does this work?

Suppose you are currently at step `i` and the steps allowed are `[2,6,19]`

What could have been your previous step?

Since only those steps that are present in step_array are allowed, you must have been at:-

```
i-2
i-6
i-19
```

Since only these steps will lead you to i in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite some time to understand this problem today. Lets hope I am able to explain. I will try to explain with an example which i think would make it simpler to understand.

```
For example if step sizes are: [1,3,5]
n = number of stairs
n(0) = 1 way, to be at the same position it will be 1 way
n(1) = [1] = 1 
n(2) = [1,1] = 1
n(3) = [1,1,1] , [3] = 2 ways
n(4) = [1,1,1,1] , [1,3] , [3,1] = 3 ways
n(5) = [1,1,1,1,1] , [1,1,3] , [1,3,1] , [3,1,1] , [5] = 5 ways
n(6) = [1,1,1,1,1,1] , [1,1,1,3] , [1,1,3,1] , [1,3,1,1] , [3,1,1,1] , [3,3] , [1,5] , [5,1] = 8 ways

now if we look closely, n(6) can be achieved in 3 ways:
1. taking 1 step first
2. taking 3 step first
3. taking 5 step first

so other way to write n(6) would be:
n(6) = [1,1,1,1,1,1] , [1,1,1,3] , [1,1,3,1] , [1,3,1,1] , [1,5]   >> 1st step is 1
       [3,1,1,1] , [3,3]                                           >> 1st step is 3
       [5,1]                                                       >> 1st step is 5
```

so we can say:

```
n(6) = 1st step is 1 + {[1,1,1,1,1] , [1,1,3] , [1,3,1] , [3,1,1] , [5]} >> 1+n(5) 
       1st step is 3 + {[1,1,1] , [3]}                                   >> 3+n(3)
       1st step is 5 + {[1]}                                             >> 5+n(1)
```

that is:

```
n(6) = n(5) + n(3) + n(1)
or 
n(6) = n(n-1) + n(n-3) + n(n-5)
```

but what if (n-3) or (n-5) becomes negative, then it is not considered, as there wont be any step taken

so if i is in [1,3,5] >> steps allowed 
we can say that:
if (n-i) > 0, we add this to the function for calculating the steps

alternatively:
for i in [1,3,5] >> steps allowed:
if (n-i) >= 0
  we add the steps

so if n was 4: and i = [1,3,5]
it would be:

```
n(4) = n(3) + n(1)
```

so above steps can also be written as:

```
n(0) = 1  
n(1) = 1 
n(2) = n(1) 
n(3) = n(2) + n(0)
n(4) = n(3) + n(1) 
n(5) = n(4) + n(2) + n(0)
n(6) = n(5) + n(3) + n(1)
```

Hope i am able to explain. Solution using python as below:

```
def simplestairs(n,X):

    if n == 1:
        return 1

    cache = [0 for _ in range(n+1)]
    cache[0] = 1
    cache[1] = 1

    for i in range(2,n+1):
        for x in X:
            if i - x >= 0:
                cache[i] += cache[i-x]

    return cache[-1]

n = 6
X = {1,3,5}

simplestairs(n,X)
```